# order by datetime with type varchar

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-order-by, mariadb, varchar

I have a question and I didn't find the solution on stackoverflow. So here is my question:

How can I order a Varchar on datetime (dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss) priorities in my PHP file? 
I have a SQL table with a "registerdate" column. Its type is Varchar (datetime isn't possible due to other table issues). My SQL ORDER BY query is:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY registerdate DESC LIMIT 3
```

This results in:

```
12-11-16 11:03:54 
06-12-16 19:05:22 
06-12-16 15:03:30
```

How I want it:

```
06-12-16 19:05:22
06-12-16 15:03:30
12-11-16 11:03:54
```

In my php file I register the time with $datetime=date("d/m/y H:i:s"); and in my table it is a Varchar who looks like 03/12/16 12:19:33

I think I have to CONVERT it in my SQL Query but I don't know how. Who can help me? Many thanks in advance!

-----SERVER/SQL INFO-----

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Servertype: MariaDB
Serverversie: 10.0.27-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server
Protocolversie: 10
```

Comment: ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(registerdate , '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s')

Comment: Thank you Kamal. 

Solution: ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(registerdate , '%d/%m/%y %H:%i:%s')    
So uppercase H instead of an lowercase h and lowercase y instead of an uppercase Y.

Comment: Keep in mind that performance will not be good.  You really should store datetime values in a `DATETIME` (or `TIMESTAMP`) datatype.  This comment applies to all of the suggested solutions so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users u ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(u.registerdate, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') DESC LIMIT 3
```

or

```
SELECT *, STR_TO_DATE(u.registerdate, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') as newdate FROM users u ORDER BY newdate DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but both don't work. I forgot to say that in my php file I register the time with `$datetime=date("d/m/y H:i:s");` and in my table it is a Varchar who looks like `03/12/16 12:19:33`.

Comment: Sorry, too early. It doesn't work. The date is ordering well, but the time isn't.

Comment: What kind of error do you have? Or it works, but  the results aren't in correct order?

Comment: Try ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(u.registerdate, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s'))

Comment: I get no errors but it doesn't order. It orders wrong (i don't see any logic in it) or it doesn't order at all when I change little things.

Comment: You are using 24h values, so change format string to '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s' - it's ok now

Comment: Many thanks saltydog. I didn't use an uppercase H and an uppercase Y instead of an lowercase.

Comment: Ooops, my miss, year in your case must stiil  'y' (year in XX format), not in 'Y' (XXXX format), but 'H' - 100%

Comment: Yes, doesn't matter, it helped me much!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you too if you are using sql server.

SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY Cast(registerdate AS datetime) DESC

Comment: Thanks, but it don't work.. 

I forgot to say that in my php file I register the time with `$datetime=date("d/m/y H:i:s");` and in my table it is a Varchar who looks like `03/12/16 12:19:33`

Answer (score 0):

For an Oracle database the syntax would be:

SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY TO_DATE(registerdate, 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS') DESC